# how do I store system.web.authorization details in an external config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to maintain different user authorization lists for different environments.  I know that connectionstrings can be broken out in an external file with configSource, but how would I do this for the following?

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="someuser1"/>
  <allow users="someuser2"/>
  <allow users="someuser3"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a roles provider instead of adding each individual user to your allow list. Then for each environment you specify which group has access:

```
<!-- Development -->
<authorization>
    <allow roles="development"/>
</authorization>

<!-- Q/A-->
<authorization>
    <allow roles="test"/>
</authorization>

<!-- Production -->
<authorization>
    <allow roles="*"/>
</authorization>
```